# Can't modify protocol option of request object in sailsJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, express, sails.js

I'm using library that checks req.secure option to continue without errors. But also my application is deployed to heroku and I'm using custom middleware to check "x-forwarded-proto" header and set req.secure as true and req.protocol as "https", but actually these options stay the same after such operations. I made debug output immediately after assigning values to req.secure and req.protocol and I can see that these options wasn't modified. It goes definitely through that code because I see debug information for "x-forwarded-proto" == "https" case. Are there any restrictions for setting such vars in express js?

SailsJS v0.10.5

**Code of my custom middleware in config/http.js:**

```
if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https'){
          req.secure = true;
          req.protocol = 'https';

          sails.log('Secure headers detected: secure - ', req.secure, ', protocol - ', req.protocol);
}
```

Output:

```
debug: Secure headers detected: secure - false , protocol - http
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the reason of such behavior. Request object **req**, that is defined in **expressJS**, has such properties like `protocol` and `secure` and these properties are defined using `__defineGetter__` function. This function is **feature of V8** and it sets value that is not visible in object on logging and **is not settable**, only in case if you will define setter with `__defineSetter__` function.

More information can be found here: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/ecma-5-mozilla-features-implemented-in-v8#objectprototype